# Get Activity after startActivity(Intent i)

Tags: android, android-activity

In one method i start a new activity

```
public void start(){
    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, Screen.class);
    mContext.startActivity(i);
    //Here i want to get the new activity

    Activity a = ...
    //Do something with new activity        

}
```

After calling `starActivity()` i need to get that new Activity and doing something with it.

Is it possible??

EDIT:

Well i have these methods on my Screen class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loadedScreen = false;
}


public void loadScreen(String folderResources, String nameXml, String nameScren){
         //Do something
    }
```

`loadScreen` read an XML file and create by code all user interface, instead of doing in `onCreate`

In another class I call foo():

```
public void goToScreen(String nameScreen){
    Class screen = Screen.class;
    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, screen);
    mContext.startActivity(i);

    //Here in screen.getMethod... i need use a instance of Screen, which i think it have to be created in `startActivity()`

        Method loadUrl = screen.getMethod("loadScreen", String.class, String.class, String.class);

      loadUrl.invoke(screen, "folder-s","screen1","screen1.xml");


}
```

I need call to `loadScreen` after `startActivity`because this method load all views. I use reflection for doing this. So i need get that new Activity

Comment: What do you mean by get the activity?

Comment: As in ? `Screen` activity not under your control ?

Comment: When you call `startActivity()` , an activity is created (this is a new object). I want to use one method from this new Activity just after `mContext.starActivity()`

Comment: @Bae you can start new activity do some computation and return the result to previous activity using `startActivityForResult(intent, ResultCode)`.

Comment: only for couriosity, what do you want to do with the activity ?

Comment: I edit my question! @ArnaldoGaspar I want to call one method using reflection.

Comment: Why not just using onCreate(), which is the right place to load the UI of an Activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After calling starActivity() i need to get that new Activity and doing something with it.

Once you call `startActivity()`, the other activity does not yet exist -- it will not exist for some time.

> I need call to loadScreen after startActivitybecause this method load all views.

Call `loadScreen()` from `onCreate()` of the `Screen` activity.

If you wish to pass the values of `folderResources`, `nameXml`, and `nameScren` to `Screen`, do so by calling `putExtra()` on the `Intent` you use with `startActivity()`. Then, `Screen` can call `getIntent().getStringExtra()` in `onCreate()` to retrieve those values, in order to pass them to `loadScreen()`.

Comment: Yes! Finally i use intent to pass `nameScreen`, `nameXml` and `folder` to the new activity instead of using loadScreen. I didn't remember this system to pass parameters to an activity! Thanks for all!

Comment: Does the Activity's process not yet exist, or just it's view?

Comment: @SamusArin: You have no way of knowing. From your standpoint, nothing related to the activity needs to exist.

Comment: I want to know whether an **`Activity`** is pushed onto the **Back Stack** while **`show`**-ing an *"open file as"* **`DialogFragment`**, or if the user cancels beforehand, to help decide what to do in the **`DialogFragment`**'s **`OnActivityResult`**. The **`OnBackStackChanged`** listener wired to the **`DialogFragment`** doesn't fire. I don't think the built-in *"view file chooser"* (that the *"open file as"* **`DialogFragment`** launches with **`StartActivityForResult(Intent(ACTION_VIEW))`**) opens the chosen **`App`** (ie, *Jota*) as a **`Fragment`**, but rather as it's own **`Activity`**.

Comment: **`OnBackStackChanged`** also doesn't fire when the built-in *"view file chooser"* itself is displayed, so am assuming that it isn't a **`Fragment`** either, but an **`Activity`**.